# Simple example for pthread_join deadlock

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, deadlock, pthread-join

I am looking for a very simple example to demonstrate a deadlock using `pthread_join`; however, this is not trivial.

I started with this:

```
void* joinit(void* tid)
{
  pthread_t* tid_c = (pthread_t*)tid;
  int retval = pthread_join(*tid_c, NULL);
  printf("In joinit: tid = %d, retval = %d \n", *tid_c, retval);
  return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thread1;
  pthread_t thread2;

  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, joinit, &thread2);
  pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, joinit, &thread1);

  pthread_join(thread2, NULL);  

  return 0;
}
```

But however, it says 'EINVAL' (invalid argument) because `thread2` is not yet specified when `pthread_create` for `thread1` is called.

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried this and it worked, but the problem is, it only works SOMETIMES because sometimes I get EIVAL again.
I AM checking errno in the method joinit!

Comment: Yes you don't get to decide when a thread is started, the OS does that.

Comment: Yes, I know. I need to have a reliable deadlock situation.

Comment: Also, you `pthread_join(thread2, NULL)` in `main()` in the main thread, the other `pthread_join()` can cause a race condition.

Comment: If I didn't do this, the main thread will return, exit will be called and all threads will die.

Comment: You'll need to make sure that the threads don't access their parameters until both threads have been created — you need some additional synchronization between the threads.  A semaphore would be one option. You could perhaps do it with a pair of mutexes passed to the threads (along with the other threads `pthread_t *` — so you'd end up with a structure being passed).  In this case, the main code would create the structures and the mutexes and lock the mutexes.  After both threads are created, the main thread would release the mutexes.  Should you join the other thread in `main` too?

Comment: Okay, now I found a way...I created a third thread which will run a while(true) and the main thread will join this. Then the other two threads will have enough time to join each other and a deadlock is created...

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler! I will have a look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just wanting to demonstrate that a `pthread_join` can cause a deadlock, you could do something similar to the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* joinit(void* tid)
{
    printf("In %#x, waiting on %#x\n", pthread_self(), (*((pthread_t*)tid)));
    pthread_join((*((pthread_t*)tid)), NULL);
    printf("Leaving %#x\n", pthread_self());
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread1 = pthread_self();
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, joinit, &thread1);
    joinit(&thread2);
    return 0;
}
```

This will cause the main thread to wait on the spawned thread and the spawned thread to wait on the main thread (causing a guaranteed deadlock) without the need for extra locking primitives to clutter up what you are trying to demonstrate.

And to answer some of your questions more directly:

> it says 'EINVAL' (invalid argument) because `thread2` is not yet specified when `pthread_create` for `thread1` is called.

... and from one of your comments ...

> I tried this and it worked, but the problem is, it only works SOMETIMES because sometimes I get EINVAL again.

In your code, you call `pthread_create` consecutively to spawn the 2 threads:

```
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, joinit, &thread2);
pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, joinit, &thread1);
```

In your `joinit` code, you grab the thread handle passed in to join on:

```
pthread_t* tid_c = (pthread_t*)tid;
int retval = pthread_join(*tid_c, NULL);
```

The reason this *sometimes* works and others you'll get `EINVAL` has to do with [time slices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) allocated to each thread's context and [sequencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). When the first `pthread_create` is called you will have a valid handle to `thread1` after it returns but the handle to `thread2` is not valid yet, at least not until the 2nd `pthread_create` is called.

To this, when a thread is created, the act of the thread coming "alive" (i.e. the thread function actually running) could take some extra time even though the thread handle returned is valid. In these instances, there is a chance one thread can execute more code than might be "expected". In your code, both `pthread_create` functions *might* happen to have been called in the time slice allocated for the main thread which *could* give each spawned thread enough "time" before hitting the `pthread_join` statement allowing `tid_c` to point to a valid handle; in the `EINVAL` case, `pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, joinit, &thread2)` was called and the spawned thread hit the `pthread_join(*tid_c, NULL)` **before** `pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, joinit, &thread1)` could give `thread2` a valid handle (causing the error).

If you wanted to keep your code similar to how it is now, you would need to add a lock of some sort to ensure the threads don't exit or call anything prematurely:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* joinit(void* tid)
{
    /* this can be above the lock because it will be valid after lock is acquired */
    pthread_t* tid_c = (pthread_t*)tid;
    int retval = -1;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    printf("%#x waiting on %#x\n", pthread_self(), *tid_c);
    retval = pthread_join(*tid_c, NULL);
    printf("In joinit: tid = %d, retval = %d \n", *tid_c, retval);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    /* get the lock in the main thread FIRST */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, joinit, &thread2);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, joinit, &thread1);
    /* by this point, both handles are "joinable", so unlock  */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    /* can wait on either thread, but must wait on one so main thread doesn't exit */
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: its worth mentioning that running just your code will not make OP aware if deadlock has happened. You should check return val of pthread_join for that. In this case pthread_join will return 35 (EDEADLK) and any one of thread will simply return.
`int ret=pthread_join((*((pthread_t*)tid)), NULL);
printf("%d %s\n",ret,strerror(ret));`

output:
In 0x7fb4740, waiting on 0x77ca700
In 0x77ca700, waiting on 0x7fb4740
35 Resource deadlock avoided
Leaving 0x77ca700
0 Success
Leaving 0x7fb4740

In essence here pthread_join handled deadlock for us and skipped waiting part.

Comment: @kalimba .. actually running just my code causes a deadlock on some systems (like Windows and OpenBSD); others it _might_ return a value that _might_ indicate that a deadlock condition occurred (e.g. a kernel setting). On my Slackware system `EDEADLK` is defined as `22` (not `35`). POSIX is a loose standard, so while checking the return value of `pthread_join` is important, it's well more important to understand what a dead lock is and to avoid it in the first place (as the OP was asking to demonstrate one and presumably would avoid such a case in the first place).

Comment: appreciate your response :) My information was limited to posix only.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for your error is that you have two threads each waiting for the same thread to terminate because of the call to `pthread_join` in `main`. Another problem is that you don't ensure each thread correctly sees the other thread's ID.

Fix it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t thread1;
pthread_t thread2;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;
int go = 0;


void* joinit(void* ptr)
{
  // wait until both thread IDs are known
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  while (go == 0)
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  pthread_t* tid_c = *((pthread_t**) ptr);
  printf("About to wait\n");
  int retval = pthread_join(*tid_c, NULL);
  printf("In joinit: tid = %d, retval = %d \n", *tid_c, retval);

  // tell the other threads we're done
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  go++;
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  // setup synchronization
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);

  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, joinit, &thread2);
  pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, joinit, &thread1);

  // tell the threads to go
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  go = 1;
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  // wait for both threads to finish
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  while (go != 3)
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  return 0;
}
```